# Unable to resolve host "<insert URL here>" No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-3.0-honeycomb, urlconnection

I tried following this tutorial:
[Getting Data from the Web](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/getting-data-from-the-web-urlconnection-via-http-t351.html)

I tried implementing it on Android 3.0, the latest platform for tablets, however, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve host "www.anddev.org" No address associated with
> hostname.

You can checkout the URL that I used just to prove that the file exists.
http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/getdatafromtheweb/loadme.txt

I created a private class and extended it with asynctask. Here is the code:

```java
private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    String myString = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            URL myURL = new URL(
                "http://www.anddev.org/images/tut/basic/getdatafromtheweb/loadme.txt"
            );
            URLConnection ucon = myURL.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while((current=bis.read())!=-1) {
                baf.append((byte)current);
            }
            myString = new String (baf.toByteArray());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            myString = e.getMessage();
        }
        return myString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.setText(result);
    }
}
```

Any help out there would be appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42413023/1252158). Hope this will help

Answer (score 148):

My bet is that you forgot to give your app the permission to use the internet. Try adding this to your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: always see logcat to get the kind of error then your time consumption will be saved ...... when ever you forget to add permission .. logcat show the error ...... or either generate the crash report ...........

Comment: well i also have this problem. I have permissions set up correctly. URLConnection is working fine most of the time. But sometimes, i get this error several times in a row. It is especially hard to debug, since it only comes up from time to time...

Comment: You also have my permission to feel great for helping community

Comment: I have added this permission then also i got same Error, Is there any Problem in Emulator

Comment: You dint need to access the network state to just give your app permission to connect to the internet :)

Comment: I have encountered this error because I had turned off mobile data previously and forgot to turn it back on.  It worked fine in the office, but as soon as I was off familiar wifi, I was getting the error.  Sometimes it's the stupid things :|

Comment: What if I want to work on 3G and not wifi? I'm still getting this error in this case

Comment: Thanks lad, access network state permission removed me from the horror

Comment: I lost my valuable 8 hours just trying to fix this error. A life savor.

Comment: @KarmicCoder's answer led me to the right answer - the device was not on a network that had access to the URL endpoint I was trying to connect to!

Answer (score 120):

Please, check if you have valid internet connection.

Comment: hmm... :D I checked it, and it seems like you're right. I really don't know why, but my internet connection is okay, however, the browser inside the emulator can't access anything. That's odd.. The emulator browser was working fine a few minutes ago.

Comment: I feel like the biggest idiot. I was developing at home, instead of the office and I forgot to setup WiFi. Sometimes it takes things like these to make you remember you're an idiot sometimes. So, have a wholehearted thank you for making me feel like an idiot! :)

Comment: Same for me! somehow Wifi and airplane mode can be selected so i only had to disable the airplane mode (i wasnt really connected to the internet-palmface)

Comment: Lol dunno why I expected my S3 to login without wireless turned on.

Comment: Damit. I turned off the internet connection to the simulator, yesterday and forgot to turn it on this morning, Thanks!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
I have given both permission, but still, our user gets the above error. it reflect on firebase Crashlytics. please provide some other solution.

Answer (score 67):

May you have taken permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**BUT**

### You may have forgot to **TURN ON Internet** in Mobile or Whatever Device.

Comment: Not having the device on wifi is what caught me out! Whoops.

Comment: Restarting the emulator fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks for emphasizing the MOBILE DEVICE part.  :)

Answer (score 12):

Are you able to reach that url from within the built-in browser?

If not, it means that your network setup is not correct. If you are in the emulator, you may have a look at the [networking section](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#dns) of the docs.

If you are on OS/X, the emulator is using "the first" interface, en0 even if you are on wireless (en1), as en0 without a cable is still marked as up. You can issue `ifconfig en0 down` and restart the emulator. I think I have read about similar behavior on Windows.

If you are on Wifi/3G, call your network provider for the correct DNS settings.

Comment: hmm... :D I checked it, and it seems like you're right. I really don't know why, but my internet connection is okay, however, the browser inside the emulator can't access anything. That's odd.. The emulator's browser was working fine a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks! In my case an intranet was set as the URL causing the error, using an extranet obviously solved the issue

Answer (score 11):

if you have USB internet like me the emulator seems to dislike connection being turned on and off so you may need to restart the emulator

Answer (score 6):

This error because of you host cann't be translate to IP addresses via DNS.

> Solve of this problem :

1- Make sure you connect to the internet (check quality of network).

2- Make sure you take proper permission to access network

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error and for the issue was that I was on VPN and I didn't realize that. After disconnecting the VPN and reconnecting the wifi resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure that your device isn't on airplane mode and/or that data usage is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the Android 10 emulator and I was able to solve the problem by following the steps below:

1. Go to Settings → Network & internet → Advanced → Private DNS
2. Select Private DNS provider hostname
3. Enter: dns.google
4. Click Save

With this setup, you URL should work as expected.

Comment: This seems to be working for me so far. What exactly is this fix doing? Thanks.

Comment: @PeterG.Williams, it appears the default Android DNS on the emulator cannot do the proper domain translation and so, with this setup, we explicitly ask to use Google's DNS services.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this intermittently on wifi or LAN, but your mobile internet connection seems ok, it is most likely your ISP's cheap gateway router is experiencing high traffic load.

You should trap these errors and display a reminder to the user to close any other apps using the network.

Test by running a couple of HD youtube videos on your desktop to reproduce, or just go to a busy Starbucks.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the emulator works in some scenario.