# Unable to resolve host "<URL here>" No address associated with host name

Tags: java, android

In my Android application for reading [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) links, I am getting this error:

> java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   Unable to resolve host "example.com";
>   No address associated with hostname.

In my emulator I can connect to Google through a browser.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you give the url for which you get this error

Comment: Do you have the `INTERNET` permission?

Comment: @felix : In my browser i checked the internet connection.it works.HOw can i enable in my application?

Comment: @Octavian : Here i replaced with my original url

Comment: Make sure that your internet connection is on.

Comment: Check your WiFi connection : )

Comment: I got this error when I was testing my app on a device, in a different office with different wifi!  The device was simply not automatically connected to the wifi - stupid mistake I made, really :-)

Comment: You can verify before if isOnline:     public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&
                manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

Comment: Answers are closed but I might point someone in the right direction: For me this was a DNS issue that I need to investigate further. What it meant was I had my hostname that I needed to communicate with, but I was getting the error in the question, and none of the troubleshooting suggested was fixing it. But I am able to ping the hostname. So as a workaround, I am now connecting straight to the IP, but I'll need to investigate further with my employer's IT team why the DNS isn't working as it should.

Comment: In my case, I had to use a VPN and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You probably don't have the `INTERNET` permission. Try adding this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, right before `</manifest>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

<sup>Note: the above doesn't *have to be* right before the `</manifest>` tag, but that is a good / correct place to put it.</sup>

<sup>Note: if this answer doesn't help in your case, read the other answers!</sup>

Comment: Check your WiFi connection : )

Comment: Thanks! This helped me twice. Always the same issue. 1st time saw a comment is more useful than its answer. Also you got more up votes than the answer.

Comment: In my case url host was not valid?

Comment: @ViktorApoyan you are receiving upvote for 10 years :)

Comment: @ViktorApoyan Thanks man!! you save me... Can you or anyone please share the reason behind this. (Why not working with Wifi?) and solution for that. Thanks and Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 180):

I've seen this problem in the emulator as well.  In my case, it is caused by launching the emulator, then putting the computer to sleep or changing the network connection (going from work to home, etc), then attempting to use the same emulator again.  Closing and re-launching the emulator resolves the problem in this case.

Comment: I'm encountering this same behavior, but closing/relaunching the emulator isn't fixing anything. But connecting to my work's VPN does...

Comment: This was my problem too, trying some new library to download file. searching here and there for some hour on the library documentation and on the web because it is failed to download the file.. turn out it was the emulator connection problem, lol. It wasting time, but what can I do except laughing lol. Thank you for saving my day

Comment: Saw this answer and honestly, I did not believe this would be the solution to my problem. Thank you so much Eric! Still curious how you managed to figure this out lol

Comment: I have just wasted 3 hours trying to solve this, really helpful ❤

Comment: VPN was my issue; I had connected after loading the emulator.

Comment: Android emulator's bug...

Comment: Wasted so much time, thank you for this

Answer (score 84):

It is **WiFi bug** due to `wifi disable or not properly connected.`

> Simply Reconnect the wifi will solve the issue.

Answer (score 47):

> Unable to resolve host “”; No address associated with hostname

you must have to check below code here on your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and **most important at least for me:-**

**enabled wifi connection or internet connection on your mobile device**

Comment: it helped me ... Thanks ... Check WiFi on your Emulator

Comment: my net was not enabled ...opps ..!!! thanks for the check .. sometimes one makes the dubmest of mistakes

Answer (score 12):

Check you have:

1- Access to Internet connectivity.

2- The permission for internet is present in the manifest.

3- The url host is valid and registered in a trusted domain name server.

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes, although you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the AndroidManifest and you have a WiFi connection, this exception can be thrown. In my case, I have turned off WiFi and then turned it on again. This resolved the error. Weird solution, but sometimes it works.

Comment: Just had this happen to me. Working fine then all of a sudden get this problem. WiFi off and on solved it. Odd!

Comment: Why do you think it is happening?

Answer (score 10):

`""` it seems you are trying to resolve this host , which is invalid.

Check for rss URL

**Update**
Following are the possibilities

**1** Your browser is configured with proxy, app not

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxyhost.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");
```

**2** Your browser has access to internet. not app

**3** can be an SSL issue if URL is secured

Comment: I typed my url  in browser and can access.

Comment: what did you type in browser?

Comment: the URL for retrieving data.It directs to a xml page.

Comment: but it seems your app isn't trying to access that url , from error message it seems it is looking at `""`

Comment: No no , i just posted without Url .Error shows with the site address.

Comment: Your browser is configured with proxy, app not.- How can i configure it?                                      
Your browser has access to internet. not app - yes                     
can be an SSL issue if URL is secured - How can i know this is secured?

Comment: if its on `https` then secure, check for browser configuration if it has proxy configured, modify your code to talk to proxy

Comment: its an http address, so its not secured. what you mean by talk to proxy.

Comment: How can i configure my app using - System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxyhost.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");

Answer (score 10):

Some times on the emulator, I have to launch the browser before my app can access the Internet.

Comment: Correct 1st you should check browser whether internet is working or not. If still not just wipe the data of emulator and re-run the app.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. My virtual device was showing a crossed-out WiFi icon at the top bar of the device. I rebooted the virtual device and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

It could be due to below reasons: -

1. Either you dont have INTERNET permission in manifest file. If so then please use this statement `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. Or you are connected to a network but your internet connection is not working. Like you are connected to a Wi-Fi but it doesnt have internet connection or Mobile data on your phone is ON but you dont have data connectivity on your phone.

Point# 2 is interesting and its not assumption, I have tested the same at my end.

Hope this will help you

Summved

Answer (score 4):

It's not your fault bae, I've had this happen sometimes when the emulator's in a weird state. Just restarting the emulator helped me.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had that error when I'm connected to VPN on my host but not on simulator. Turning the VPN off solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

In my case problem was with WIFI working with IPV6 and my domain did not have IPv6 adress

Comment: How did you resolve it? I have noticed randomly on xyz mobile network at times mobile device only gets IPv4... where my domain work on both network IPv6 and IPv4 from most of network but only on that xyz network doesn't work on IPv4.

Answer (score 3):

I Had the same problem, and it was because the simulator somehow got in airplane mode, once this was disabled my App worked fine :-)
I had tried everything, rebuild, clean+build and reboot android studio and reboot the computer, even reinstalling android studio..

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the app on an emulator, make sure that it is properly connected to the internet. If it is not, the easiest way of solving it is reopening the emulator or creating a new device.

Answer (score 1):

Check permission for INTERNET in mainfest file and check network connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to resolve host “”; No address associated with hostname

I had this issue and I solved it by this way.
change

http://hostname/abc/def/ghi/name.php

to

http://ipaddress/abc/def/ghi/name.php //http://97.68.XX.YY/abc/def/ghi/name.php

I solved this by this way...you have to give server ip address instead of hostname/servername.

Please try this and comment your feedback.

Comment: Well, this is like suggesting to take the bus when someone asks why their car is not working. After all, one purpose of hostnames is that the underlying IP address can change anytime.