# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host exception coming for some urls

Tags: android, networking, android-networking, android-internet

I am trying to download some images from some urls. The issue is that some of them are getting downloaded fine but some are giving error - `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "image-url": No address associated with hostname.` Necessary permissions are already given, wifi is working fine too. Following is the exception:-

```
02-20 11:34:45.230: W/System.err(9336): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "image-url": No address associated with hostname.
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
02-20 11:34:45.230: W/System.err(9336):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
02-20 11:34:45.230: W/System.err(9336):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.aquimo.downloadengine.ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator.loadFile(ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator.java:103)
02-20 11:34:45.240: W/System.err(9336):     at com.aquimo.downloadengine.ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator.access$0(ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator.java:72)
02-20 11:34:45.250: W/System.err(9336):     at com.aquimo.downloadengine.ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator$1.run(ResourceDownloaderAndAllocator.java:37)
02-20 11:34:45.250: W/System.err(9336):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-20 11:34:45.250: W/System.err(9336): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
02-20 11:34:45.250: W/System.err(9336):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
02-20 11:34:45.260: W/System.err(9336):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
02-20 11:34:45.260: W/System.err(9336):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
```

Following is the code:-

```
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
ucon.setDoInput(true);
ucon.connect();
InputStream inputStream = ucon.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
Log.d(TAG, "inputStream size = " + inputStream.available());
int downloadedSize = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bufferLength = 0;
while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
    Log.i(TAG, "Progress: " + "downloadedSize:" + downloadedSize);
}
fileOutput.close();
```

Comment: `No address associated with hostname` what URL you are passing ?

Comment: http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png

Comment: are you trying in device which is behind the firewall ?

Comment: I am trying in my nexus4 and it does not has any firewall or antivirus. Moreover I can open this url in my browser.

Comment: Seems to be some configuration with your dns. Are u getting the images from the internet or from a local server?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475024/httpresponse-using-android-issue-execute-always-causes-exception

Comment: @KevinJoymungol I am getting them from internet. Also please note that some other urls are working fine and are returning the file.

Comment: @HariharanTamilan No help from this link too.

Comment: Please post the url, I can have a look. Also try your code on a data connection and see if it works.

Comment: @KevinJoymungol The url is posted above in the comments. http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810004.png. You can check this..

Comment: I have also had this issue on a Galaxy S3 (Sprint Android 4.3). I have experienced the exception being thrown from SipManager.Register(...) and from OnError raised from SipAudioCall.Listener when dialing. If I use the IP address instead of hostname, everything works fine. The failure is confined with the underlying API's ability to resolve the hostname. Oddly enough, manually resolving the hostname using InetAddress resolves successfully and then using the IP address in the URI works. The issue is only cleared when the phone is restarted and then works for a while before always erroring again.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "image-url": No address associated with hostname
```

This means you are passing `"image-url"` as the URL to load. Unless you have this mapped to a valid IP, you're not going to get anything.