# java.net.UnknownHostException Unable to resolve host "accounts.google.com": No address associated with hostname while inserting rows in bigquery

Tags: java, android, google-bigquery, google-api-java-client, google-api-client

Hi I am working on android app in which I have integrated BigQuery. I see we are getting a lot of exception sometimes while inserting records in BigQuery tables. We are not expertise in this but started to learn this new technology. It would be great if you guys can help me on this.

```
   java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "accounts.google.com": No address associated with hostname
          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
          at com.google.a.a.c.a.c.a(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
          at com.google.a.a.c.r.p(HttpRequest.java:972)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.h.a(TokenRequest.java:307)
          at com.google.a.a.b.a.a.b.f(GoogleCredential.java:384)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.c.h(Credential.java:489)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.c.a(Credential.java:217)
          at com.google.a.a.c.r.p(HttpRequest.java:859)
          at com.google.a.a.b.d.c.c(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
          at com.test.utils.c.c(CommonUtility.java:2730)
          at com.test.services.AppInstallIntentService.onHandleIntent(AppInstallIntentService.java:71)
          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
   Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
          at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Posix.java)
          at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
          at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
          at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
          at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
          at com.google.a.a.c.a.c.a(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
          at com.google.a.a.c.r.p(HttpRequest.java:972)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.h.a(TokenRequest.java:307)
          at com.google.a.a.b.a.a.b.f(GoogleCredential.java:384)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.c.h(Credential.java:489)
          at com.google.a.a.a.a.c.a(Credential.java:217)
          at com.google.a.a.c.r.p(HttpRequest.java:859)
          at com.google.a.a.b.d.c.c(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
          at com.test.utils.c.c(CommonUtility.java:2730)
          at com.test.services.AppInstallIntentService.onHandleIntent(AppInstallIntentService.java:71)
          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: How is your device connected to Internet? Mobile? WiFi? Do you have any proxy?

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli I don't have idea because customers logs are not being uploaded. What are the possibilities for this error ?

Comment: I believe you are not connected with the internet or you are unable to access the internet.

Comment: Have you check this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475024/httpresponse-using-android-issue-execute-always-causes-exception

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-times-out/41542528#41542528. it will check for internet connection and only request if connection available. So you will not get the `Unable to resolve Host` until you mistype the URL.

Answer (score 16):

This Exception Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined.

This exception is also raised when you are connected to a valid wifi but router does not receive the internet. Its very easy to reproduce this:

Connect to a valid wifi
    Now remove the cable from the router while router is pluged-in

You will observe this error!!

You can't really solve this, You can only notify the user gracefully. (something like - "Unable to make a connection")

also make sure you have added the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

If not, add below line outside the application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Are you able to got to `accounts.google.com` on your machine in a browser?