# Xamarin Android Picasso Java.Lang.RuntimeException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA

Tags: java, android, xamarin, crash, picasso

I am using Picasso to load a graphic from remote server. Below is the code:

```
return Picasso.With(context)
    .Load("https://exampledomain.com")
    .Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.icon_placeholder)
    .Error(Resource.Drawable.icon_error)
    .Get();
```

I intermittently would have crash with message:

**Java.Lang.RuntimeException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)**

and also:

**java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "exampledomain.com": No address associated with hostname**

NOTE - since the crash happened few days ago, i have not been able to reproduce this crash on the app.

Anyone have same problem with a solution they could kindly share?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759802/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host-accounts-google-com-no-a).

Comment: Hi @JoeLv-MSFT, thank you for your reply mate, i made sure i got permission right, and i can confirm this since my App is connecting (uploading and downloading data correctly during it's operation. I am having this issue when client is using our app from their site)

I wonder if this issue could be caused by their DNS server onsite?