# Unable to resolve host "url" :No address associated with hostname

Tags: android

Long story short, An app I have keeps getting an error saying

```
Error registering: Unable to resolve host "storywriters.dataone.com.au" :No address associated with hostname"
```

It was working fine but I had a problem that led me to uninstall and install it again and then this problem came, Any help? Sorry, if I'm being vague, I'm awful at this.

I've seen other answers, talking about the manifest but I'd like an answer on how to access it on either android or computer.

Comment: delete emulator and install in new emulator....

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but can you be specific? I'm horrible at this stuff and I don't know what this emulator is, all I want is to use it again and voila, I'm gone.

Comment: Are you using emulator ? Try to ping this host from your operating system terminal. If the host also not responding , you need to flush dns cache.

For Windows: "ipconfig /flushdns".
For OSX 10.8 and above: "sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder"

Comment: If emulator means "Using it on a computer", No. This problem is only coming from my Android phone. I'm sorry for the inconvenience, once this problem's over I surely won't have any other problem to ask for again.

Comment: this is not the place to ask this type of questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve host "<url here>"; No address associated with hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a programming question. You are talking about an app you have. This site is for apps you develop yourself as a programmer. Go to stackexchange instead.

Comment: Sorry, for the inconvenience. I'll head there for help. Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not provided the INTERNET permission. Try adding this to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file, right before :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I've heard this answer before but do I have to access the manifest on a computer? If so, is this why an emulator is needed? Also, is there anything I need to know about the emulators? Such as which to get, where to put this permission in. I'm sorry if I'm bad at explaining this, I'm new to this and I'm doing a terrible job.

Comment: Without giving this permission you wont able to run your application even on your Real Device.Because Manifest is working like a config file, and if you provide permission in that then it will allow your application to access internet.

Comment: I'm viewing the manifest and there I see the permission for internet. The exact words you told me to put. I can copy and paste that part here if that's needed.

Comment: Check if you have given this permission or not?<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> the same thing?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Both permissions given but still, our app user got this issue, Looking for a solid solution