# Connect to get JSON from URL

Tags: android, host

I make an application that get some data from server,on my localhost the app work fine,and when I upload server side to real host,I test the new URL (mydomain.comuv.com/get_data.php) in the browser it work,but within my app return "unable to resolve host "mydomain.comuv.com": No address associated with host name" 
that's the code :

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...params){

        InputStream is=null;
        String result="";

        try{
         // httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
         httpclient=Singleton_con.getInstance().getHttpclient();
        // httppost= new HttpPost("http://mydomain.comuv.com/image_pull_test/get_image.php");
            httppost= Singleton_con.getInstance().getHttppost();
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){

            if(pd!=null)
                pd.dismiss();  //close the dialog if error occurs
            Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());

        }


        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }

        //parse json data
        try{
            records.clear();
            Toast.makeText(context,""+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONArray jArray =new JSONArray(result);

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String record=json_data.getString("title")+"__"+json_data.getString("poster")+"__"+json_data.getDouble("rate");
                records.add(record);


            }


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error pasting data "+e.toString());

        }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){

        if(pd!=null) pd.dismiss(); //close dialog
        if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        mCustom_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify the ListView to get new records


    }

}
```

Comment: Are you debugging using a real device? If not do you have network turned on in your emulator?

Comment: Also please add the relevant lines of code to your question.

Comment: I experimented it in emulator and real device and the same error

Comment: try adding www after your http://  . I got this error before and it was resolved when I added www. I'm not entirely sure why, but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you  set [the internet permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355961/1874460)?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: yes I did and added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />