# Android app with many users complaining cant connect on Wifi but works on mobile network

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking

I have an Android app on play store with about 500,000 downloads. Its a wallpaper app that retrieves all wallpapers from my server.

I have so many users giving negative ratings saying the app wont load walls on wifi but works on cellular network. here is one of the latest reviews

> Doesnt work on wifi First day it works on wifi. Then. Suddenly stops
>   working and doesnt load on wifi. Works good on mobile net. Please look
>   into this.

I and my beta team have never had this issue happen on our devices or emulator.

This is the library im using
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19

Looking at my crashlytic reports i see this is one of the top non-fatal issues

***I have censored out the actual address.***

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.a.b.o: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.*****.io": No address associated with hostname
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:158)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
Caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.*****.io": No address associated with hostname
       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:470)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
Caused by android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
       at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Posix.java)
       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:220)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:176)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:108)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:482)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:465)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:447)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:353)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:468)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:410)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:532)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
       at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
       at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

What could be the issue? Could it be a issue with users wifi network they are on? or an issue with my webserver, which is DreamHost?

Comment: `"www.*****.io": No address associated with hostname` - just to confirm, did you censor the URL?

Comment: Yes i apologize. I will update question with that info

Comment: It definitely isn't an issue with your server.  Its a DNS issue.  Possibly the DNS hasn't updated yet if its a new server, or possibly its blocked by the ISP of that wifi.  Have they tried on wifi at another location?

Comment: Well i personally cannot get the issue to happen. I only see user complaints in reviews.

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname (look at the answers other than the accepted answer).