# Unable to resolve host “<example.com>”; No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, android-volley

I am currently using volley to access my web server database. But i was getting this error:

```
Unable to resolve host “<url here>”; No address associated with hostname
```

My friends can access them when they install the APK I gave them and I can access it with my own phone using office's internet. But when I'm home I can't access it with my phone using my home wifi but I can access is by writing the URL in my PC browser, I can access it with my AVD.

I have looked at the answers here: [Unable to resolve host "<url here>"; No address associated with hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Actually I dont know if I should comment there or create a new question

I have give `internet` permission and restarted my phone's wifi, my wifi router, and even restarted my phone but still the same result. Any other solutions? thank you

Comment: I have wrote the exact URL in my browser and it can access it, basically I can access it anywhere else except with my phone using my home wifi

Comment: Have you tried the URL in a browser on the device? Your question says that you tried from a PC.

Comment: can you access the url from your browser from your home wifi??

Comment: I found out that i can't access it using my phone's broswer too by writing the url there but using my PC's browser with my home wifi i can access it

Comment: Interesting problem. Could be it related with dhcp bugs, https://rudd-o.com/archives/wifi-dhcp-network-not-working-with-your-android-phone ?. Waiting for other comments.

Comment: you need to use an IP address and your server should accept connections from all hosts.

Comment: @user3576118 can you specify, how you called the url ? and post some code that you have tried that will be helpful to solve

Comment: i can access it perfectly fine now, without any code changes and without doing any settings

Comment: saw a lot reported from the installs in the field. same device same wifi sometime works sometime not. Waiting if someone knows better.