# Retrofit is not able to find the host

Tags: android, retrofit2

I was following a tutorial on this link http://thetechnocafe.com/getting-started-with-retrofit-in-android/ to refresh my knowledge on how to use retrofit.
But when I get the response, it calls ***onFailure*** with the following error ***Unable to resolve host "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com": No address associated with hostname***.
I have cheked the implementation and it's correct, I have even checked it with postman and the API is returning the correct expected JSON.
The service is setup as follow:

```
package cd.acgt.acgtexp.service;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class NetworkService {
private static NetworkService mInstance;
private static final String BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";
private Retrofit mRetrofit;

private NetworkService() {
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static NetworkService getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new NetworkService();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
    return mRetrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
}
```

}

My API interface is implemented as follow :

```
public interface JSONPlaceHolderApi {
   @GET("posts/{id}")
   public Call<Post> getPostWithID(@Path("id") int id);
}
```

And here is where I call my API :

```
public void testApi() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(TAG, "test starts" );

    NetworkService service = NetworkService.getInstance();
    JSONPlaceHolderApi apiInterface = service.getJSONApi();
    apiInterface.getPostWithID(1).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "DONE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure : " + t.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure : " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

It's going only in the onfailed method and throwing the error that there is no address associated with the hostname.

Comment: Does your app have the Internet permission?

Comment: yes, there is internet permission

Comment: please check browser and see internet working on your emulator?\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname.

Comment: I have the same Issue. Changing the WiFi does work on the same device. The same problem occur time to time both on ANDROID and IOS. Problem is probably on API.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using emulator. check the network icon its connect with internet or not. its connected - this error raised in host address. otherwise, close the emulator and restart.

share network connected to emulator,

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-10/f6dcac4b-5203-4c98-8cf2-dcac86d98fb9

Answer (score 0):

If you use VPN in your computer then emulator will not be able to connect to internet. Disconnect from VPN and try again.

Comment: I am not using a VPN and I am able to access the API from the emulator browser

Answer (score 0):

Better test in physical device to avoid hassles. Still if you need emulator,
Don't use / at last of base url, rather prepend it to suburl