# Android Java: Geocoder grpc falied exception

Tags: java, android, grpc, ioexception, geocoder

I'll walk you through the key points, bear with me for a while.

**What I'm Doing**

I'm getting the location from location manager and using Geocoder to get city name.

**How I'm Doing it**
In on location changed function, I crate a new thread and make a new address list to get addresses from geocoder in a try catch block.

**The Code**

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("onLocationChanged","Before if");
    if (location != null){
        Log.d("if location not null","start");
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged: Location : " +location);
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                    Log.d("TAG", "onLocationChanged address: "+addresses);
                    city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    search(city);
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("IOException","at geocoder " + e.getMessage());
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Slow Connection...Try Later.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

    }
    else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.d("Location is null", "else");
        Toast.makeText(fl.getContext(),"Cannot Access Current Location...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

}
```

**What's Happening**

Based on the logs, location is being fetched but grpc failed exception occurs when geocoder.getFromLocation function is invoked.

**The Logs**

```
D/onLocationChanged: Before if
D/if location not null: start
D/TAG: onLocationChanged: Location : Location[gps 33.565110,73.016913 hAcc=5 et=+18822d15h39m59s954ms etAcc=+1ms alt=0.0 vel=0.0 bear=0.0 vAcc=1 sAcc=1 bAcc=30 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=96]}]
D/IOException: at geocoder grpc failed
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
        at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
        at com.rehnsehan.rehnsehan.ExploreActivity$5.run(ExploreActivity.java:194)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore: (23.0.1) [WatchStream]: (51c23b2) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:436)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:272)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:228)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

**Note: This function was working just fine for the last month and did not throw any exception.**

**Thanks, Any suggestions or feedback is appreciated.**

Comment: The IOException looks like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-host-name

Comment: You don't have internet access in your app according to the error

Comment: @CristianHoldunu the entire app is running online, all other functions work fine...

Comment: @Shahzaib have you fixed it?