# Unable to resolve host: No address associated with hostname

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp, cloudflare

In my Android application I use my Rest API, delivered via the cloudflare network (with active proxy). Very often the first connection to the okhttp API receives the following error:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException
Unable to resolve host "mydomain.com": No address associated with hostname
```

After the user retries one or more times, subsequent connections are successful. If there is some downtime with API requests, the error is likely to occur again.

I cannot understand what causes this problem. If it can depend on cloudflare or if there is a way to solve on the okhttp side.

do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue, I created a new question with more information about my specific case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474481/unable-to-resolve-host-mydomain-com-no-address-associated-with-hostname

Comment: encountered same issue, and it's happened intermittently and randomly with no fix pattern. I alrd read some answer on other thread, and i would not accept answer that simply that reconnect wifi would solve this because it's not technical solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with one of my crypto wallets only to discover my app needed to be updated and once I updated the app everything was smooth from that point on. When I first went to the Play Store to see if I had any updates due, there were none but when I searched specifically for my wallet app in the Play store an update was needed. So make sure you search for the specific app that is giving you the problem in the Play store.

Comment: Thanks a mill. I wasted a long time having checked for updates in the update area. Odd the update was only only visible searching for the app.

Comment: This is not relevant to programmers...

Answer (score 0):

Or you have no internet on the device

or you forgot to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

permission in manifest.xml

@see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-host-name)

Answer (score -3):

I have also the same issue but after restarting android studio it solved my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).