# Unable to resolve host "mydomain.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, flutter

### Error

UPDATE: Solved, it was a configuration error in Samsung Knox.

Here is another question about

```
SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'mydomain.com'
(OS Error: Unable to resolve host "mydomain.com": No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

### Background

My app calls my API:s, plain and simple. It used to work the other day, but after an update it stopped working and I got the error above. (The update had minor changes, should not affect this)

1. Flutter app.
2. Android device, Samsung Tab A (SM-515).
3. The device has internet connection.
4. The app has all the permissions needed to access internet.
5. I am able to visit a site on the same domain using the browser.
6. Restarting Wi-Fi does not help.
7. Disabling Wi-Fi and using mobile network does not help.
8. Restarting device does not help.
9. Uninstalling the app and reinstalling it does not help.
10. Uninstalling the app and installing the **debug** version helps, it can now access the API.
11. Uninstalling the debug version and reinstalling the release version does not help, same error again.
12. The exact same release version work on a different, but identical device.
13. Requests are sent with `package:http/http.dart`, `get` method.
14. The API does not have any authentication, anonymous access allowed.
15. I replaced `http.dart` with `package:dio/dio.dart`, same result.
16. I've updated flutter and all packages and done a complete rebuild, same result.

I've seen this error before, but only temporarily. The errors are logged to Sentry, but no errors from this device are logged, implicating that the app does not have internet access at all.

It is extremely frustrating. I've spent two days on this, my last option is to factory reset the device. I don't want to do that because I want to know what the cause is and how I can prevent it from happening again.

I need help on how to debug. What can I look for in `adb logcat`?

**Edit:**
Here are the permissions set in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

**Edit 2:** More info in list.

**Edit 3:**
So I was going to try to get DNS info in the app using `package:dns_client/dns_client.dart`, but as I suspected the app does not access internet at all. I got the same error for the domains `cloudflare-dns.com` and `dns.google.com`.

Using `InternetAddress.lookup("google.com")` I got the error `SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'google.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)`.

**Edit 4:**
I created a new Flutter app from scratch. And it works when adding the permissions. The error is most likely related to the permissions, but somehow the app don't get it on one specific device. Is there a permission cache on Android that persists through uninstalls and restarts?

The info about the app says it has all the permissions needed. Is it a bug in Android?

**Edit 5:**
Running the command `adb shell dumpsys package package.name` to list permissions and got this result, which shows that network access is granted.

```
install permissions:
      android.permission.INTERNET: granted=true
      android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE: granted=true
      android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE: granted=true
```

Comment: "No address associated with hostname" suggests to me that the internet connection is working and DNS resolution actually returned an NXDOMAIN response (meaning "not found"). Such a response may be cached by DNS servers (including local DNS proxies), which may explain the intermittent nature of the problem. To verify this, try using `1.1.1.1` explicitly as the DNS server for the device.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that (setting to `one.one.one.one`) and `dns.google` to no avail.

Comment: I can add that the domain is on Azure DNS. Not that is should matter because I can access the domain from the same device. I've also tried changing the TTL in a desperate attempt to see if it helps.

Comment: To rule out the possibility that Flutter is caching something, have you tried to clear all app data and caches for the release app? I thiiiiink this should be done on uninstall, but I'm not sure if anything could stay behind.

Comment: Yep, I've also updated flutter and all packages to the latest major version. I can easily say that this is the weirdest error I've ever gotten.

Comment: Did you add the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 on manifest?

Comment: @NabinDhakal Yes, it has permissions as I stated in the list and it also works on other devices. I added a list with the permissions to avoid confusion.

Comment: Maybe the permission has been revoked/overridden manually on this device? I'm not sure what is possible in that regard on recent Android versions.

Comment: Yes, that might be the case. It looks fine in the permissions info for the installed app, but somehow it seems to be blocked anyway. I think it is related to permissions.

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid. We use Samsung Knox to deploy applications to a kiosk device. I used a test profile where I added `live.outlook.com` as an allowed URL. It turns out that `*` was added to blocked URL:s (only affects kiosk apps, not Chrome??). Clearing allowed URL:s solved the issue. Two days wasted.