I want to add location permission in my app
enter image description hereI just want to know some thing,.. I am practicing API Integration in Flutter.. From a Video tutorial I made a weather app which tell us weather but in the app I have declare a cityname: every time I open the app it tells me the weather of that specific city,( this is all I made through a tutorail)
then I made some changes in it and make a texfield for city and when I enter any city it tells me the weather of that city..
Know I want that the app detects the location from user and tell the user weather of his location in which he is,, for that i use GEO locater package and when i open the app it is working fine but when i send the apk to a friend which  is in a different city he got an error which is :
ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'api.openweathermap.org' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7), uri=https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/ forecast?q=Islamabad&APPID=
can any one please tell me what I can do
I want when any one opens the app, the app will show weather according tu his current location

Probably should add some code.

Duplicate of Unable to resolve host "" No address associated with host name

Failed host lookup: 'api.openweathermap.org' is referring to an unsuccessful dns request. This can be caused by either bad connection or a mistyped url address, mainly the 'api.openweathermap.org' part. Since I can verify your url is working fine it was probably your friends bad connection that caused this. Clear evidence is the 4kb/s internet speed I can see in the top left of the screenshot.
To solve this you should have the http request wrapped in a try catch and have a friendly way to tell your user that the app can't connect to the server:
try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Islamabad&APPID=70c3ab0d0010e2192577ba5de02a5030"));
      // handle the incoming data
    } catch (error) {
      // handle user not being connected to the internet
    }

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6355961: Another reason for why it may not work is the app not being able to connect to the internet because of missing internet permission in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file. Add this:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

right above the </manifest>

Few tips on how to improve your question and save yourself a lot of time:

Before posting an answer check for duplicates. It might save you a lot of time
Include the misbehaving code and isolate the issue. You will find that a lot of times it becomes so easy you can solve it yourself.
Try using the same type of app yourself (the release apk you sent to your friend).
Do not share your api keys around. It exposes them for possible abuse - I'm talking about the &APPID=70c3ab0d0010e2192577ba5de02a5030 in the image.


Bro , I have sent the apk to different friends but they all got the same error . It is not common that every one have Internet issue

@MuhammadDaniyalKhan Have you tried the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Yes , now it's work fines after this permission..thanks
