# Detection error with Azure Cognitive Services: Unable to resolve host "centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"

Tags: java, android, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure Cognitive Services for an Android mobile application and got stuck on an error. Help!

Currently using the FACE API and trying to retrieve a response about the Facial Attributes but keep getting this error when I didn't have it earlier:

`ERROR: Detection failed: Unable to resolve host "centralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com": No address associated with hostname`

Previously, I was only testing the facial detection with the drawFaceRectangle method, and had no errors with the endpoint but now that I'm trying to request the facial attributes I get this error. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829779/unable-to-resolve-host-insert-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to resolve the issue. Was just missing the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the **`AndroidManifest.xml`** which will enable your app the permission to use the internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```