# No adress associated with hostname in android studio while reading an url

Tags: android, android-studio, web-scraping, rss, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to read the data from an url using HttpURLConnection in Android. I refered the from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355498/unable-to-resolve-host-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname.). I follow the same but I'm getting an error **java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "thehindu.com": No address associated with hostname**. I have enabled all permissions. My Main Activity code is

```
package com.example.urlconnect;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
        checkAndRequestPermissions();
        new connection().execute();
    }  
    private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionInternet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        int permissionCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        int readPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readPhoneState_tm = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        int writePhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int coarseLocation = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        int readSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (permissionInternet != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
        }if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (permissionCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        }
        if (readSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        }
        if (readPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (writePhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (coarseLocation != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (readPhoneState_tm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        //Log.d("test1", "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.INTERNET, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                        //Log.d("permissions..",""+permissions[i]);
                        //Log.d("grant..",""+grantResults[i]);
                    }
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.INTERNET) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //Log.d("test2", "sms & location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                        // Log.d("test3", "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) ||ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {
                            showDialogOK("SMS and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            switch (which) {
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                    checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                    break;
                                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                    // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                    break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                        //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }})
                .create()
                .show();
    }
    public class connection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
        public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 5000;
        public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 150000;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {

                URL RssUrl=new URL("https", "skymetweather.com", 80, "/");
                Properties systemProperties = System.getProperties();
                Log.d("ss4","yyyyy");

                HttpURLConnection conn1=(HttpURLConnection) RssUrl.openConnection();
                conn1.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
                conn1.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn1.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);



                Log.d("ss3","yyyyy"+systemProperties.getProperty("https.proxyPassword"));
                conn1.connect();

                Log.d("ss1",""+conn1.getResponseCode());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("chand",""+e);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.urlconnect">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>  
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to resolve host "<insert URL here>" No address associated with hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829779/unable-to-resolve-host-insert-url-here-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Comment: ya it is duplicate, I already refer the url in the question.

Comment: it's another question not the one you mentioned in your question :)

Comment: ya you are correct. But even though I followed those answers, I'm unable solve my purpose because of I already given proper permissions.

Comment: Have you tried checking your internet connection or connect device to another router or something ?

Answer (score 0):

On your `<application>` please set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` int the `AndroidManifest.xml`.
And set inside it

```
 <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I have added as you suggested above but same error.